# How to toggle proprietary Nvidia drivers and opensource drivers easily?

Tags: linux, debian, arch-linux, nvidia, nouveau

I want to use opensource nvidia drivers and also proprietary nvidia drivers if i want to and want a way to toggle between them easily.
Like if i want to use cuda things, i would just toggle reboot and use proprietary drivers.

If i want as daily other use cases , i want to stick with opensource drivers.I also see opensource tends to support wayland.

I'm in Debian. But This questions is for all linux distro.

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

The video driver gets loaded when X initializes, you can watch the details in `/var/log/Xorg.log`.

There is no way to tell X to "toggle" between drivers. There is also no way to load both drivers, as both use the same hardware.

So any kind of "toggling" would involve restarting the X server (with a different configuration file). Which means you'll get logged out of your desktop.

If you are happy with this solution, you can script that (though it's probably a nontrivial amount of work).

If you want something that lets you switch between drivers while staying logged in to your desktop, then this is not possible.

If it's really important to you, buy a second Nvidia card, and run one driver on one card, and one driver on the other card.

---

If you are fine with a restart of the X server, the first step is to write the two `xorg.conf` files for each driver, and learn how to restart the X driver on your distro with a specific configuration file (details depends on your distro, your desktop environment, your display manager, etc. Read the docs).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm fine if i restart happens, i just want to have toggle way so that if i  toggle and restart , i want desired driver. I wouldnt buy nvidia in future, but i want to have this in my current nvidia driver . :)